# Tools/methods for creating demo videos of iPhone/iPod Touch games?

Tags: video, screen-recording, demo

I'd like to create a simple demo video of a game for iPhone and iPod Touch.  **What tools do people use for this?**  Ideally I can capture the device's screen... as opposed to the simulator.  Also the game uses tilt controls... hence capturing the device's screen helps put actual game play into the demo video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this stackoverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200049/is-there-a-way-i-can-capture-my-iphone-screen-as-a-video